# Limsup and convergence subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $\lim\sup a_n=l$. Then we know that it has following characterization :

(1) $\forall\epsilon>0$, $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\exists p\geq n$ such that $a_p>l-\epsilon$

(2) $\forall\epsilon>0$, $\exists k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n\geq k$ we have $a_n<l+\epsilon$.

Now I try to construct a subsequence of $a_n$ which converges to $l$. I want to be sure that my construction is true or not.

Step 1 :By (2), for $\epsilon=1$, $\exists k_1$ s.t $\forall n\geq k_1$ we have $a_n<l+1$. By (1) we have, for same $\epsilon=1$, and choose $n:=k_1$, then $\exists p_{k_1}\geq k_1$ s.t $a_{p_{k_1}}>l-1$. Thus, for $\epsilon=1$, $\exists p_{k_1}\geq k_1$ s.t $l-1<a_{p_{k_1}}<l+1$.

Step 2 : By (2), for $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$, $\exists k_2$ s.t $\forall n\geq k_2$ we have $a_n<l+\frac{1}{2}$. By (1), for same $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$, choose $n:=k_2$ then $\exists p_{k_2}>\max\{p_{k_1},k_2\}$ s.t $a_{p_{k_2}}>l-\frac{1}{2}$. Hence for $\epsilon=1/2$ $\exists p_{k_2}>\max\{p_{k_1},k_2\}$ such that $l-\frac{1}{2}<a_{p_{k_2}}<l+\frac{1}{2}$ (such $p_{k_2}$ exists because $\mathbb{N}$ is unbounded from above)

If we continue this process, we will construct a monotone increasing $p_{k_1}<p_{k_2}<...<p_{k_N}<...$ such that $l-\frac{1}{N}<a_{p_{k_N}}<l+\frac{1}{N}$ for any $N\in\mathbb{N}$. Finally take $N\to\infty$ and conclude the claim.

Comment: @JohnD Hi, Sir. What is missing in my construction. I want to be sure about my proof. Can you look at this?